# Question on regular expression

Tags: regex, scripting

I have a string of the type

```
"X-Request-Recipients: assignee:tammalac; cat:angub; cat:bashas; cat:bhattacs; sev:nukalas; sev:abc@somewhere; sub-all:majumdaa;sub-all:mayakunp; sub-all:srinivay; sub-all:tammalac; "
```

Now question what is the regular expression expression to extract any number of strings after : and before ;.

P.S. I would be accessing this from a perl script.

Comment: Hi Pradeep, I can`t see any string-example above.

Comment: Do you have samples of what your strings look like?

Comment: What have you already tried? What are the constants? (Will there ever be spaces? Is it always letters/numbers? etc.) `\w+:\w+;` works fine for me.

Comment: I have updated the source string in the question

Comment: I think you just broke your question and the existing answers. You added a colon (:) without a matching semicolon (;). There are eleven colons and ten semicolons. Please consider clarifying this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex that matches these parts would be

```
\w:([^;]+);
```

or, more specifically

```
(?:username|subscriber):([^;]+);
```

Use the contents of group 1 as the result.

```
\w:      # a word character and a colon
(        # begin group 1
  [^;]+  #   any character except a semi-colon, at least one
)        # end group 1
;        # a semi-colon
```

Comment: Thanks this worked.. Appreciate the clarity you provided here. How do i keep traversing till I reach the end of the stirng?

Comment: Ignore my prev comment. I found the solution myself :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression:

```
:([^;]+)
```

Using your sample text this will work.